# Call function from object instantiated in one class in another

Tags: c++

I have two classes, both of which need to be able to call the same instance of entitymanager

```
class Engine
{
  EntityManager::Entitymanager EManager;
}
```

And I need to add an object to a vector contained by this particular instance of Engine. What I want to do is be able to add a bullet spawned by the player to the vector that contains all my entities.

```
class Player : Entity
{
  void SpawnBullet() {Engine::EManager.Add(BULLET);}
}
```

The above returns this error:

error: object missing in reference to ‘Engine::EManager’

How do I resolve this? Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: The above does not return this error because the keyword is `class`, not `Class`.  Please copy and paste your code; it's hard to answer the question when details in the question are wrong:  who knows what other details are wrong?

Comment: Apologies, the typo on my behalf was a mistake copy pasted twice, it does not appear in the actual code. I've doublechecked to ensure there aren't any other mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access EManager without a class instance associated with it.

There are 2 solutions for this.

You have to have an instance of Engine around in order to access EManager:

```
class Engine {
    EntityManager::Entitymanager EManager;
};
```

Then you can access `EManager` this way:

```
m_engine.EManager.Add(BULLET)
```

You have to make `EManager` a *static* member of Engine (that is, it will be bound to the class scope only, you won't need an instance for it):

```
class Engine {
public:
    static EntityManager::Entitymanager EManager;
};
```

Then you can access it as you already did (It has to be public, or your classes have to be friends).

I feel however that you need to get [a good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and **understand** what you are trying to achieve. And while you're at it, get one on software engineering too ;).

Comment: Cheers, this got everything working. I suspect you're right, I've been muddling along so far and I could do with working through a solid book on C++.

Answer (score 1):

> I have two classes, both of which need
>   to be able to call **the same instance**
>   of entitymanager

It seems you need to implement [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Have a look at the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), maybe you'll have a good design of your classes!

Comment: After getting it to work with the above answer, I went off to read up on singletons as suggested, and then implemented one, and managed to tidy up my code quite a bit as a consequence. Cheers!